# Ubuntu upgrade failed

Tags: upgrade

I've tried to upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 but it failed and result in "unstable system" or something.

`sudo apt-get install -f` doesn't work
`sudo do-release-upgrade` says I'm up to date.

So I though of deleting my current unstable 13.04 Ubuntu and install it fresh new(**if there isn't something else i can do**), but the problem is that I have dual boot with windows.

how can I delete my Ubuntu and install it fresh new, without touching windows?

Comment: Try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Comment: "No new release found" :(. Thnx anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of Ubuntu allows you to upgrade 12.10. If you want to delete your current version select Erase Ubuntu 12.10 and install 13.04. If you just want to upgrade use the "upgrade" option

[image]

Comment: Edit: there is no such option.
I've read about os-uninstaller, it works but mess up the boot-loader so I won't be able to access windows after the removal of ubuntu. if I remove ubuntu and then install it again, would I be able to access windows again?

Comment: Yes that will work fine, just use something like [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). I'm surprised that option isn't available. Maybe it's been taken out in the newest version(s). Strange...

Comment: How did it work out? Everything resolved?

Comment: Yeah, everything works. Thnx for the help !

Comment: No problem, glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

If you bring up software-sources either under synaptic or the standalone utility and go to the repositories section, select the updates tab and take a look under notify me of a new ubuntu version. It should read for any new version.

Answer (score -1):

if you like fresh ubuntu. You can delete ubuntu partition with gpart and reinstall ubuntu 13.04... and choose install ubuntu alongside windows

Good luck!

Comment: Actually I think this will install a third operating system; Windows, 12.10 _and_ 13.04 instead of replace the current version of Ubuntu.